# how to get datepicker value in code behind in asp.net webforms on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have initiated date picker for start date and end date and i have tried the following, but its not working for me am getting empty value.

.cs code

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeforeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Page.Request.Form["StartDate"]);
    CurrentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Page.Request.Form["EndDate"]);
    string dt = StartDate.Text;
}
```

.aspx code

```
  <div class="DatePicker" style="height:30px;background-color:white !important;">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" name="StartDate" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true" placeholder="Start Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>  
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" name="EndDate" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true" placeholder="End Date" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>   
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-md-2">
                     <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click"  CommandArgument="YourArgumentValue" OnClick="MyButton_Click"/>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to read the Text property of your textboxes:

```
string startDate = StartDate.Text;
string endDate = EndDate.Text;
```

Or if you want to use a DateTime variable:

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate.Text);
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate.Text);
```

Comment: I tried getting it as value and as a text. I am getting the empty value.

Comment: If you try removing the ReadOnly property of the textboxes?

Comment: thank you...Now am getting an value after removing Readonly property .

Answer (score 0):

```
String startDate = StartDate.Text.ToString();
String endDate = EndDate.Text.ToString();
```

By giving ID and `runat="server"`, you can use all html controls in your code behind.

And you should separate `ID` and `name` `attributes`, don't give them same value..

Also try adding `CausesValidation="False"` to your button.

EDIT:

By reading your comments You have to cast the variable to TextBox:

```
String startDate = (StartDate as TextBox).Text.ToString();
```

Comment: i already gave it but it is not working.u can see from the above code. 
                                                                                                             
 Error CS1061 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference).

Comment: Error CS1061 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)......getting this error

Comment: Never seen a textbox having value property. To read and write in a textbox we make use of **Text** property. There isn't any **Value** property for a textbox control. Please update your answer with `String startDate = StartDate.Text` and `String endDate = EndDate.Text`